# Boost spirit qi parsing compilation error when long sequence of grammar is used

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit-qi

```
void Parse(string const& input)
{
    string::const_iterator begin = input.begin(), end = input.end();

    auto pin_parser    = qi::copy(+(qi::char_("a-z")));
    auto val_parser    = qi::copy(qi::float_ >> ':' >> *(qi::float_) >> ':' >> qi::float_);

    auto connect_parser = qi::copy( 
                                qi::lit("CONNECT") >> qi::space >> pin_parser[boost::phoenix::bind(callback, "PIN1", qi::_1)] >> qi::space
                                >> pin_parser[boost::phoenix::bind(callback, "PIN2", qi::_1)] >> qi::space
                                >> val_parser >> qi::space >> val_parser >> qi::space
                               );

    bool is_succ = qi::parse(begin, end, +connect_parser);
    std::cout << "Succ " << is_succ << std::endl;
}
```

I am trying to parse the following string using boost::spirit::qi.

**CONNECT clk sda 1.020::1.030 0.200::0.00**

**CONNECT da doai 0.100::0.050 0.040::0.300**

And then send the tokens parsed through callback. But getting following error.
**The compilation problem only comes when trying to parse long sequence. The compilation problem goes away if grammar sequence is shorter.**

Say for example if i parse following, using the grammar below, then there is no compilation error.

**CONNECT clk 0.200::0.00**

**CONNECT da 0.040::0.300**

```
auto connect_parser = qi::copy(qi::lit("CONNECT") >> qi::space >> pin_parser[boost::phoenix::bind(callback, "PIN1", qi::_1)] >> qi::space
                                >> val_parser >> qi::space
                               );
```

```
spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, 0l> >, 2l>&>, 1l>]'
PASDFParser.cpp:81:62:   required from here
/calypto/tools/install/boost/boost_1_59_0/rhel7/m64/include/boost/fusion/container/vector/convert.hpp:27:13: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct boost::fusion::detail::barrier::as_vector<13>'
             type;
             ^
In file included from /calypto/tools/install/boost/boost_1_59_0/rhel7/m64/include/boost/fusion/container/vector/detail/as_vector.hpp:15:0,
                 from /calypto/tools/install/boost/boost_1_59_0/rhel7/m64/include/boost/fusion/container/vector/convert.hpp:11,
                 from /calypto/tools/install/boost/boost_1_59_0/rhel7/m64/include/boost/fusion/container/vector.hpp:30,
                 from /calypto/tools/install/boost/boost_1_59_0/rhel7/m64/include/boost/fusion/view/zip_view/detail/at_impl.hpp:12,
                 from /calypto/tools/install/boost/boost_1_59_0/rhel7/m64/include/boost/fusion/view/zip_view/zip_view.hpp:19,
                 from /calypto/tools/install/boost/boost_1_59_0/rhel7/m64/include/boost/fusion/view/zip_view.hpp:12,
                 from /calypto/tools/install/boost/boost_1_59_0/rhel7/m64/include/boost/fusion/sequence/intrinsic/swap.hpp:15,
                 from /calypto/tools/install/boost/boost_1_59_0/rhel7/m64/include/boost/fusion/sequence/intrinsic.hpp:23,
                 from /calypto/tools/install/boost/boost_1_59_0/rhel7/m64/include/boost/fusion/include/intrinsic.hpp:11,
                 from /calypto/tools/install/boost/boost_1_59_0/rhel7/m64/include/boost/proto/fusion.hpp:22,
                 from /calypto/tools/install/boost/boost_1_59_0/rhel7/m64/include/boost/proto/core.hpp:21,
                 from /calypto/tools/install/boost/boost_1_59_0/rhel7/m64/include/boost/proto/proto.hpp:12,
                 from /calypto/tools/install/boost/boost_1_59_0/rhel7/m64/include/boost/spirit/home/support/meta_compiler.hpp:19,
                 from /calypto/tools/install/boost/boost_1_59_0/rhel7/m64/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/meta_compiler.hpp:14,
                 from /calypto/tools/install/boost/boost_1_59_0/rhel7/m64/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/action/action.hpp:14,
                 from /calypto/tools/install/boost/boost_1_59_0/rhel7/m64/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/action.hpp:14,
                 from /calypto/tools/install/boost/boost_1_59_0/rhel7/m64/include/boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp:14,
                 from /calypto/tools/install/boost/boost_1_59_0/rhel7/m64/include/boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp:16,
                 from PASDFParser.h:17,
                 from PASDFParser.cpp:10:
/calypto/tools/install/boost/boost_1_59_0/rhel7/m64/include/boost/fusion/container/vector/detail/cpp03/as_vector.hpp:28:12: note: declaration of 'struct boost::fusion::detail::barrier::as_vector<13>'
     struct as_vector;
```

Answer (score 0):

By avoiding to define rules (instead using `auto`), you are pushing the limits of automatic attribute propagation and compatibility.

It doesn't help that you're explicit matching space characters *with attributes*. It will immediately help to `qi::omit[]` those. Although likely you just should consider using the appropriate skipper.

You can help the system just a tiny bit by telling it more about your intentions, it makes everything easier, e.g.:

```
auto pin_parser = copy(qi::as_string[+qi::char_("a-z")]);
```

### Demonstration?

I couldn't really reproduce your issue after minimal cleanup. Of course I had to imagine a callback (I show a version that works regardless of whether `as_string[]` is applied);

**Live On Coliru**

```
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>

void Parse(std::string_view input) {
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    using boost::phoenix::bind;
    using qi::copy;
    using namespace qi::labels;
    auto begin = input.begin(), end = input.end();

    struct {
        void operator()(std::string_view name, std::vector<char> const& value) const {
            std::cout << name << ": " << quoted(std::string_view(value.data(), value.size()))
                      << " (vector)\n";
        }
        void operator()(std::string_view name, std::string_view value) const {
            std::cout << name << ": " << quoted(value) << " (string-like)\n";
        }
    } const callback;

    using qi::space;
    // auto space = qi::copy(qi::omit[+qi::space]);
    auto pin_parser = copy(+qi::char_("a-z"));
    //auto val_parser = copy(qi::lexeme[qi::float_ >> ':' >> *qi::float_ >> ':' >> qi::float_]);
    auto val_parser = copy(qi::float_ >> ':' >> *qi::float_ >> ':' >> qi::float_);

    auto connect_parser = copy(                            //
        "CONNECT" >> space                                 //
        >> pin_parser[bind(callback, "PIN1", _1)] >> space //
        >> pin_parser[bind(callback, "PIN2", _1)] >> space //
        >> val_parser >> space                             //
        >> val_parser >> space                             //
    );

    auto ok = qi::parse(begin, end, +connect_parser);
    std::cout << "Succ " << ok << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    for (
        auto input :
        {
            R"(CONNECT clk sda 1.020::1.030 0.200::0.00)",  // no trailing space
            R"(CONNECT da doai 0.100::0.050 0.040::0.300)", // no trailing space
            R"(CONNECT clk sda 1.020::1.030 0.200::0.00 )",
            R"(CONNECT da doai 0.100::0.050 0.040::0.300 )",
            R"(CONNECT clk sda 1.020::1.030 0.200::0.00 CONNECT da doai 0.100::0.050 0.040::0.300)", // no trailing space
            R"(CONNECT clk sda 1.020::1.030 0.200::0.00
               CONNECT da doai 0.100::0.050 0.040::0.300)",
        }) //
    {
        Parse(input);
    }
}
```

Prints

```
PIN1: "clk" (vector)
PIN2: "sda" (vector)
Succ 0
PIN1: "da" (vector)
PIN2: "doai" (vector)
Succ 0
PIN1: "clk" (vector)
PIN2: "sda" (vector)
Succ 1
PIN1: "da" (vector)
PIN2: "doai" (vector)
Succ 1
PIN1: "clk" (vector)
PIN2: "sda" (vector)
PIN1: "da" (vector)
PIN2: "doai" (vector)
Succ 1
PIN1: "clk" (vector)
PIN2: "sda" (vector)
Succ 1
```

### Problem #1: Semantic Actions

The `Succ 0` lines betray a problem: the semantic actions run even when the parse is not successful. See [Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil)

Alternatively, using a skipper allows absense of non-mandatory whitespace:

```
auto pin_parser = copy(qi::as_string[qi::lexeme[+qi::char_("a-z")]]);
auto val_parser = copy(qi::lexeme[qi::float_ >> ':' >> *qi::float_ >> ':' >> qi::float_]);

auto connect_parser = copy(                   //
    "CONNECT"                                 //
    >> pin_parser[bind(callback, "PIN1", _1)] //
    >> pin_parser[bind(callback, "PIN2", _1)] //
    >> val_parser                             //
    >> val_parser                             //
);

auto ok = qi::phrase_parse(begin, end, +connect_parser, qi::space);
```

Prints [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93aaa064ddff339a):

```
PIN1: "clk" (string-like)
PIN2: "sda" (string-like)
Succ 1
PIN1: "da" (string-like)
PIN2: "doai" (string-like)
Succ 1
PIN1: "clk" (string-like)
PIN2: "sda" (string-like)
Succ 1
PIN1: "da" (string-like)
PIN2: "doai" (string-like)
Succ 1
PIN1: "clk" (string-like)
PIN2: "sda" (string-like)
PIN1: "da" (string-like)
PIN2: "doai" (string-like)
Succ 1
PIN1: "clk" (string-like)
PIN2: "sda" (string-like)
PIN1: "da" (string-like)
PIN2: "doai" (string-like)
Succ 1
```

### Fixing The Semantic Actions

To fix the problem with the semantic action firing for incomplete/failing (branch) parses you would build the entire result, at least until you know the rule doesn't fail or get backtracked:

```
auto connect_parser =
    qi::copy("CONNECT" >> pin_parser >> pin_parser >> val_parser >> val_parser);

px::function callback = [](std::string_view pin1, std::string_view pin2) {
    std::cout << "pin1: " << quoted(pin1) << ", pin2: " << pin2 << "\n";
};

auto ok = qi::phrase_parse(begin, end, +connect_parser[callback(_1, _2)], qi::space);
```

See it **[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9054db98a897a31)**

### Rules, No Semantic Actions

At this rate, we might just as well use rules, which will allow us to have implicit lexemes ([Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965)) and not needing `qi::omit[]`, `qi::lexeme[]`, `qi::copy`, `qi::as_string[]` or other type coercion hints:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/579c57a873056864)**

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

using Pin  = std::string;
using Pins = std::pair<Pin, Pin>;

std::vector<Pins> Parse(std::string_view input) {
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    using It     = std::string_view::const_iterator;

    qi::rule<It, Pin()> pin_parser = +qi::alpha;
    qi::rule<It>        val_parser = qi::float_ >> ':' >> *qi::float_ >> ':' >> qi::float_;
    qi::rule<It, Pins(), qi::space_type> connect_parser =
        "CONNECT" >> pin_parser >> pin_parser >> val_parser >> val_parser;

    auto begin = input.begin(), end = input.end();
    std::vector<Pins> data;
    qi::phrase_parse(begin, end, +connect_parser > qi::eoi, qi::space, data);
    return data;
}

#include <fmt/ranges.h>
int main() {
    for (
        auto input :
        {
            R"(CONNECT clk sda 1.020::1.030 0.200::0.00)",
            R"(CONNECT da doai 0.100::0.050 0.040::0.300)",
            R"(CONNECT clk sda 1.020::1.030 0.200::0.00 )",
            R"(CONNECT da doai 0.100::0.050 0.040::0.300 )",
            R"(CONNECT clk sda 1.020::1.030 0.200::0.00 CONNECT da doai 0.100::0.050 0.040::0.300)", // no trailing space
            R"(CONNECT clk sda 1.020::1.030 0.200::0.00
               CONNECT da doai 0.100::0.050 0.040::0.300)",
        }) //
    {
        fmt::print("{} -> {}\n", input, Parse(input));
    }
}
```

Prints

```
CONNECT clk sda 1.020::1.030 0.200::0.00 -> [("clk", "sda")]
CONNECT da doai 0.100::0.050 0.040::0.300 -> [("da", "doai")]
CONNECT clk sda 1.020::1.030 0.200::0.00  -> [("clk", "sda")]
CONNECT da doai 0.100::0.050 0.040::0.300  -> [("da", "doai")]
CONNECT clk sda 1.020::1.030 0.200::0.00 CONNECT da doai 0.100::0.050 0.040::0.300 -> [("clk", "sda"), ("da", "doai")]
CONNECT clk sda 1.020::1.030 0.200::0.00
               CONNECT da doai 0.100::0.050 0.040::0.300 -> [("clk", "sda"), ("da", "doai")]
```